# Is there any way of doing while loop for dates to get 12 month rolling sales amount in Presto SQL?

Tags: presto, trino

I want to implement below logic in Presto SQL:

DECLARE @StartDate DATE = '2016-10-01' ;
DECLARE @EndDate   DATE = '2021-05-02' ;

WHILE (@StartDate <= @EndDate)
BEGIN
print @StartDate;

DECLARE @12MonthStartDate date
select @12MonthStartDate  = (SELECT DateAdd(YEAR, -1, @StartDate));

DECLARE @12MonthEndDate   date
select @12MonthEndDate  =  @StartDate ;

select *
from MyTable
where Date >= @12MonthStartDate and Date <= @12MonthStartDate

Based on above results, we need to do the rolling 12 months and insert the max date values into the table.

Note: we are using Presto SQL in Amperity tool.

set @StartDate = DATEADD(day, 1, @StartDate);

END;

Can any one please help with how to implement above logic in Presto SQL?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can compute a rolling sum with a window function:

```sql
SELECT dt, 
   sum(amount) OVER (
       ORDER BY dt 
       RANGE BETWEEN INTERVAL '12' MONTH PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)
FROM my_table
```

For every row in my_table, it looks at all the rows ordered by `dt` (ascending). Then it restricts the windows to rows whose `dt` is between 12 months before the `dt` of the current row and the `dt` of the row. Finally, it computes the sum of `amount` for all the rows in that window.

See [this blog post](https://trino.io/blog/2021/03/10/introducing-new-window-features.html) for an explanation of how RANGE window frames work.

Comment: Hello Martin, I tried with your query it is taking a while to load the results for last one year.